# Cancel one term of a function by convolution

Tags: convolution

I am trying to cancel one term within a function by convolution.

$y[n] = x[n] + 2x[n-N]$

$y[n] * h[n] = x[n]$

here, $x$ is periodic and $N$ is a delay

how can I find $h[n]$ such that convolution with $h[n]$ cancels the second term of $y[n]$ but leaves the first? Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. It would be preferable to use MathJax for mathematical expressions. You can [get started here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), and a more complete reference [can be found here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hi - thank you for your reply....does any part of this question need special formatting?

Comment: @Semiclassical - thank you

Comment: Now it looks good, well done. This may look like a futile effort, but it is important on Math.SE, as it makes reading the question easier in most cases (which readers tend to appreciate), and it also helps algorithmic aspects of the site too (things like cataloging and search)

Comment: I will make sure to do so in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to outline what you can do. Formally:

$$ y_n = x_n + 2 x_{n-N} $$
$$ \frac12 y_{n+N} = \frac12 x_{n+N} + x_n $$
$$ \frac12 \left( y_{n+N} - x_{n+N} \right) = x_n $$

So you get after changing variables

$$ \frac12 \left( y_{n + 2N} - x_{n+2N} \right) = x_{n+N} $$

Plugging back into two lines above you get

$$ \frac12 \left( y_{n+N} - \frac12 \left( y_{n+2N} - x_{n+2N} \right) \right) = x_n $$

Iterate this procedure you find

$$ x_n = \frac12 y_{n+N} - \frac14 y_{n+2N} + \frac18 y_{n+3N} - \frac1{16} y_{n+4N} + \cdots $$

Now, if $x_n$ is periodic, so is $y_n$. Let $M$ be the period. Let $k$ be the smallest positive number such that $kN$ is a multiple of $M$. Then you can write

$$ x_n = \left( \frac12 y_{n+N} - \frac14 y_{n+2N} + \cdots \pm \frac1{2^{k}} y_{n+kN} \right) \sum_{j = 0}^\infty (-1)^{kj} \frac1{2^{kj}} $$

The final number is a constant that you can evaluate using geometric series. The terms in the parentheses can be expressed as a convolution of $y$ with an appropriate kernel.

---

If you are doing signal processing, then it is even easier. Since $x_n$ is periodic. Let $X_\mu$ be its discrete Fourier transform and $Y_\mu$ that of $y_n$. Then in frequency space you have

$$ Y_\mu = X_\mu [1 + 2 \exp( - i \frac{2\pi}{M} \mu N ) ] $$

where $M$ is the period of your signal. So to recover $X_\mu$ from $Y_\mu$ you just divide by the multiplication factor (which never vanishes since it is a sum of two complex numbers, one with norm 1 and one with norm 2).

If you want to approach using convolutions, your function $h$ is the inverse Fourier transform of

$$ H_\mu = \frac{1}{1 + 2 \exp( -i \frac{2\pi}M \mu N )} $$